# colored stderr when performing :!make

Tags: vimrc

I was looking for a way to color stderr so when I ran `:!make target`, I'd see the stderr lines pop up in red so I could more easily see what stopped my build.

Inspired by this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/59279, I made the following file:

~/.vim/vim_bash:

```
exec 2> >(while read line; do echo -e "\e[01;31m$line\e[0m" >&2; done)
```

Then I'd run vim via:

```
BASH_ENV=~/.vim/vim_bash vim
```

When I'd do `:!make target-with-error`, the stderr text now shows up as red.  Everything looks right to me.

I was wondering if there's a better way to color stderr.  I'm mostly interested in avoiding some "gotchas" that I haven't thought of with using the exec command in this manner.  Thanks.

---

For those who tried this and like the effect, add `let $BASH_ENV=~/.vim/vim_bash` to your .vimrc or .vim/vimrc file.

Comment: What's the question here, exactly?

Comment: You should read `:help :make`.

Comment: Definitively, use the quickfix feature, then you can always add/define a syntax highlighting to highlight the errors.

Comment: Also important: `:help 'errorformat'`